# CuPy installatioin fails on Mac OS X 10.13.6 using pip

Tags: cupy

On MacOS HighSierra 10.13.6 with Python 3.5.7 and Cuda 10.1

Both
    pip3.5 install cupy-cuda101
and
    pip3.5 install cupy
fail, with different issues.

First attempt:
    pip3.5 install cupy-cuda101 -vvvv

```
Collecting cupy-cuda101
1 location(s) to search for versions of cupy-cuda101:
* https://pypi.org/simple/cupy-cuda101/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/cupy-cuda101/
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/cupy-cuda101/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/cupy-cuda101/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/cupy-cuda101/
Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/cb/94b7aafd2344daf41c13bd152db14ed7eb2928be62575bc1421d94fbb490/cupy_cuda101-5.4.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=c422b46fc22232578d82168d73d2fd45d4ae303adad9e9e2bb6a60f6984e0438 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cupy-cuda101/); it is not compatible with this Python
```

[last line repeated for all ...]

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cupy-cuda101 (from versions: none)
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker '/private/var/folders/bz/cv2cs9y14qx6s5qf4hkz08s00000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-gfr00q13'
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cupy-cuda101
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 178, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
self.require_hashes
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 282, in prepare_linked_requirement
req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 198, in populate_link
self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 792, in find_requirement
'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for cupy-cuda101
```

---

2nd attempt:
pip3.5 install cupy -vvvv

[...]

```
************************************************************
* CuPy Configuration Summary                               *
************************************************************

Build Environment:
  Include directories: ['/usr/local/cuda/include']
  Library directories: ['/usr/local/cuda/lib', '/usr/local/cuda/lib']
  nvcc command       : ['/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc']

Environment Variables:
  CFLAGS          : (none)
  LDFLAGS         : (none)
  LIBRARY_PATH    : (none)
  CUDA_PATH       : (none)
  NVTOOLSEXT_PATH : (none)
  NVCC            : (none)

Modules:
  cuda      : Yes (version 10010)
  cudnn     : No
    -> Include files not found: ['cudnn.h']
    -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
  nccl      : No
    -> Include files not found: ['nccl.h']
    -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.
  cusolver  : Yes
  nvtx      : Yes
  thrust    : Yes

WARNING: Some modules could not be configured.
CuPy will be installed without these modules.
Please refer to the Installation Guide for details:
https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html

************************************************************
```

[...]

```
copying cupy/cuda/cupy_thrust.cu -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.5/cupy/cuda
running build_ext
building 'cupy.core._dtype' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.5
creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.5/cupy
creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.5/cupy/core
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -D_FORCE_INLINES=1 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python35/3.5.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c cupy/core/_dtype.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.5/cupy/core/_dtype.o
cupy/core/_dtype.cpp:3068:52: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
      } else if (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030700A0 && flag == (METH_FASTCALL | METH_KEYWORDS)) {
                                                 ^~~~
cupy/core/_dtype.cpp:3068:38: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
      } else if (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030700A0 && flag == (METH_FASTCALL | METH_KEYWORDS)) {
                                   ^
                                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
1 warning generated.
clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.5/cupy/core/_dtype.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcublas -lcuda -lcudart -lcufft -lcurand -lcusparse -lnvrtc -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.5/cupy/core/_dtype.cpython-35m-darwin.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1
error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cupy
```

[...]

---

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Removed the Homebrew version of python 3.5 and installed the latest python 3.7 version using a conda installer and

```
pip install cupy
```

was successful.